# Operations that preserve convexity

Tags: convex-optimization

I am trying to detemine if the expression below is concave or convex using operations that preserve convexity http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/functions.pdf.

$Var[x] = E(x^2) - E(x)^2$

- $E(x)$ is concave / convex because it is a sum of linear terms
- $E(x)^2$ is convex because of power 2
- $E(x^2)$ is concave / convex because it still is a sum of linear terms.

Would this be correct ? So then what would $E(x^2) - E(x)^2$ be since it is **convex - affine** ?

Comment: is $x$ a continuous or discrete random variable?

Comment: $E(x^2)$ is convex, because it is a sum of convex terms. So you get convex-convex, which is inconclusive.

Comment: What does it mean for a function of a random variable to be convex?

Comment: @LinAlg Ah right, I missed out that $x^2$ is convex. Lets say that the expression is convex minus affine. What would the result be ? Since an affine function is both convex and concave. A convex + affine function would still be convex I believe.

Comment: @LittleO it means for random variables $x$ and $y$ that $\lambda$ Var[$x$] + $(1-\lambda)$Var[$y$] $\geq$ Var[$\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$].

Comment: @kong subtracting an affine function from a convex function is the same as adding an affine function to a convex function, since the additive inverse of an affine function is again affine.

Comment: @LinAlg So convex - affine = convex. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to say based on the expression you have. It is much easier by using this expression:
$$\text{Var}[x] = \min_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}(x-\mu)^2.$$
It is clear that $f(x,\mu) = \mathbb{E}(x-\mu)^2$ is jointly convex, and partial minimization preserves convexity.

Comment: Thanks ! But this is not as intuitive as showing that the expression is a composition of convex functions sadly.